# How to get a length of a list from today's date only, using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am building an application using angularjs. I use mysql for database.
How do i get the length of the list which are updated on today's date only.?

for getting the length from the whole list, I used something like this

```
 app.factory('tripsheetFactory', function ($http) {
     return {
         getTripsheets: function () {
             return $http.get(urlt + '/all');
         },
         addTripsheet: function (tripsheet) {
             return $http.post(urlt, tripsheet);
         },
         deleteTripsheet: function (tripsheet) {
             return $http.delete(urlt + '?id=' + tripsheet.id);
         },
         updateTripsheet: function (tripsheet) {
             return $http.put(urlt + '?id=' + tripsheet.id, tripsheet);
         }
     };
 });

 app.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, tripsheetFactory) {
     $scope.getTotalTripsheets = function () {
         return $scope.tripsheets.length;
     };
 });
```

But i want to fetch the data only from today's date.
"tripsheets" is the list i want to fetch the data from

Comment: with this little information it's hard to answer. Please share some more code and details, data structure etc

Comment: i have an html tag which calls getTotalTripsheets which gets the length of the mysql table. I have made changed to the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `$http` data using either a success callback or since it is a promise using a `then` callback.

```
app.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, tripsheetFactory) {    
    /* call the method in factory */
    tripsheetFactory.getTripsheets().success( serverResponse){
        /* set scope var in ajax success callback */
        $scope.tripsheets= serverResponse;   
    });
});
```

Now within your html you can do things like:

```
<span>Total trips : {{ tripsheets.length}} </span>

<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="trip in tripsheets">
        Driver {{trip.driver}} drove {{trip.distance}} on {{trip.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

There are numerous ways to filter data. A simple controller filter for example:

```
var today=new date();
$scope.activeTrips= $scope.tripsheets.filter(function(trip){
       return new Date( trip.date) >= today;
 })
```